# How to hide or change layouts for specific devices in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have been developing app for mostly targeting iphone 5 and iphone 6 but when i tested in iPhone 4s some layouts get messy. i want to hide some of speicific buttons and labels from the mainView if user viewing it from iPhone4S. is there way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare these three structs in global scope then you can use them anywhere within your project.

```
struct ScreenSize {
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType {
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6P         = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
}

struct OSVersion {
    static let SYS_VERSION_FLOAT = (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue
    static let iOS7 = (OSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 8.0 && OSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 7.0)
    static let iOS8 = (OSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 8.0 && OSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 9.0)
    static let iOS9 = (OSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 9.0 && OSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 10.0)
}
```

After you have declared these in global scope you can then use this anywhere in your project:

```
if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE4_OR_LESS {
    //Device specific code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the device type and hide some UI elements accordingly.

In your `viewDidLoad` function you can do

```
if(specificDeviceType){
someButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

For getting device type you can use [Apple's UIDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Interface Builder, you can apply different constraints depending on a [size class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html). But looks like it won't work in your situation.

That is why you can detect the running device's model via [SDVersion](https://github.com/sebyddd/SDVersion) and  hide/show UI elements depending on it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this before `#include` code:`#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)`

Now in your `viewWillLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, add the following code:

```
   if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))//any version value you want
    {
[myButton setHidden:YES];
        }
```